# Custom replace for json encoding not outputting double quotes as expected

Tags: c#, json, escaping, encode

After I created my own json encoder, I realized it was replacing double-quotes with two escaping backslashes instead of one.

I realize, now, that C# has a built in `Json.Encode()` method, and yes, I have gotten it to work, however, I am left baffled by why the following code (the json encoder I had built) didn't replace quotes as I would expect.

Here is my json encoder method:

```
public static string jsonEncode(string val)
{
    val = val.Replace("\r\n", " ")
             .Replace("\r", " ")
             .Replace("\n", " ")
             .Replace("\"", "\\\"")
             .Replace("\\", "\\\\");

    return val;
}
```

The replace call: `Replace("\"", "\\\"")` is replacing `"` with `\\"`, which of course produces invalid json, as it sees the two backslashes (one as an escape character, much like the above C#) as a single 'real' backslash in the json file, thus not escaping the double-quote, as intended. The `Replace("\\", "\\\\")` call works perfectly, however (i.e., it replaces one backslash with two, as I would expect).

It is easy for me to tell that the Replace method is not performing the functions, based on my arguments, like I would expect. My question is why? I know I can't use `Replace("\"", "\\"")` as the backslash is also an escape character for C#, so it will produce a syntax error. Using `Replace("\"", "\"")` would also be silly, as it would replace a double-quote with a double-quote.

For better understanding of the replace method in C#, I would love to know why the Replace method is behaving differently than I'd expect. How does `Json.Encode` achieve this level of coding?

Comment: Aren't you replacing a `"` with `\"` and then with `\\"`? Try switching them.

Comment: @HansKesting Yeah, but you forgot, that I am dumb... lol, j/k I swear the replace function always messes with my brain... What I've done, would be like 'not' UrlEncoding the percent sign first...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're replacing `"` with `\"` and *then* replacing any backslashes with two backslashes... which will include the backslash you've already created. Perform the operations one at a time on paper and you'll see the same effect.

All you need to do is reverse the ordering of the escaping, so that you escape backslashes first and *then* quotes:

```
return val.Replace("\r\n", " ")
          .Replace("\r", " ")
          .Replace("\n", " ")
          .Replace("\\", "\\\\")
          .Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If the original string has a backslash and a double-quote in, that's entirely appropriate. For example, a variable `bar` with actual text of `foo\"baz` *should* end up as `bar="foo\\\"baz"`

Comment: Yeah, I got there in the end.

Comment: @JonSkeet I can't believe how stupid I am... LOL! It is at times like this, that I wish I could accept more than one answer... Oh, well I can upvote multiples!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
Replace("\"", "\\\""); // convert " to \"
Replace("\\", "\\\\"); // which are then converted to \\"
```

The first line replaces `"` with `\"`. The second line replaces those new `\"` with `\\"`.

As Jon says, you need the replacement that escapes the escape character to run before introducing any escape characters.

But, I think you should use a real encoder.  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can't believe how stupid I am... LOL! It is at times like this, that I wish I could accept more than one answer... Oh, well I can upvote multiples!